# Discussion board topic URL

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, permissions, url, discussion-board

Following situation:
I have a calendar with events, where attendees can register. When the event starts a topic for the event is created in a discussion board. When it is created every attendee should receive an email with a link to the topic. For this every topic in the discussion board has a column "discussionID" which is the ID of the event. But when i add a lookup to the "URL Path" it is just empty. Any idea how I can link directly to the topic?
Attendees should not be able to access the overview page where all topics are listed. They just should be able to access the topic via the link, and of course post there.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Just solved this myself by making an extra workflow on the discussion board. The URL Path worked just fine there..

Edit: The new workflow just sends an email to all attendees when a thread in the discussion board is added. I actually use encoded absolute url now, which takes the user directly to the thread

Comment: Please add some details about the workflow to make your answer very helpful!!